# How to create a table with the table header on the left side using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a table like this:
[image]

The problem is, that I want to generate it from database.

```
$sql = "SELECT name, email, tel, address FROM info where id=1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$output="<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>E-mail</th>
<th>Phone number</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>\n";

$output.="<tr>
    <td>{$row['name']}</td>
    <td>{$row['email']}</td>
    <td>{$row['tel']}</td>
    <td>{$row['address']}</td>
</tr>";

$output.="</table>\n";
```

I would like a valid code, but I have no idea, how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to have the `<th>` in there own `<tr>` it would be more like

```
$output = "<table>\n";
$output.="<tr>
<th>Name</th><td>{$row['name']}</td>
<th>E-mail</th><td>{$row['email']}</td>
<th>Phone number</th><td>{$row['tel']}</td>
<th>Address</th><td>{$row['address']}</td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: What if there are multiple rows?

Comment: The code doesn't work. The output is:
th td th td th td in one row.

Comment: Wait you don't have a loop in your code at all, so this would just do one <th><td>

Comment: No, I don't have, I've just asked. I solved my problem using your answer but I added an extra tr everywhere. It works now. tr th /th td /td /tr